# Why the need to redefine properties when implementing an interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, class, implements

I'm getting into classes and interfaces. And I got one thing about it that annoys me, this is the first time I work with these kind of things so bear with me here..

Let's say I got this interface:

```
// IFoo.d.ts
export default interface IFoo {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}
```

When I implement it in a class I do the following:

```
// FooModel.ts
import IFoo from './IFoo';

export default class FooModel implements IFoo {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;

  constructor({ foo, bar }: IFoo = { foo: 'hello', bar: 1 }) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}
```

Why do I have to implement the same properties all over again?

This is basically the same as copy-paste but with a strict convention. Also, I have to type `foo` and `bar` a total of 6 times each to get it properly assigned with default ***optional*** values, based on an interface.

Is there a more efficient way to do this too?

Edit; I'm trying to achieve the following:

A class with the properties, from which the properties can be used for typescript's checking, like this:
*interface*

```
export default interface FooDTO {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}
```

*model*

```
export interface IFoo {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}

export default class FooModel implements IFoo {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;

  constructor({ foo, bar }: IFoo = { foo: 'hello', bar: 1 }) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}
```

*controller*

```
export default class FooController {
   public static async readAll(): Array<FooDTO> {
      // some model stuff which maps query to dto
      return Array<FooDTO>result;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why would you define properties on an interface?

Comment: @Jenny O'Reilly So I can use them with type assignment, let's say I do `function findById(id: number): Array<IFoo> { ... some fetching here ...; return Array<IFoo>results; }`. it's more for consistency/explicit readability and the IDE infellisense

Comment: Ok. That's fine. But why do you also have a class that implements it?

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly so I can make a new instance of that for model creation, I want it to have the same properties as the interface and assign it, like: `const foo: FooModel = new FooModel({foo: "hi"})`; this will only manipulate foo and not bar on the new instance, since bar has a default value.

Comment: Why not get rid of `IFoo` including `implements IFoo` and use `FooDTO` as the type in the constructor?

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly But what if I have different DTO's for post, get and put/patch?

Comment: This is not described in your question. Maybe then you need different model classes too?

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly I might indeed make a new question which is very clear, I'll probably do it later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the canonical answer to "why do I have to implement the same properties all over again" is in the (increasingly outdated) [TypeScript spec](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/136f728bb011ecf1bbf0ff2aac6dacc5cb6568cb/doc/spec.md#811-class-heritage-specification):

> Note that because TypeScript has a structural type system, a class doesn't need to explicitly state that it implements an interface—it suffices for the class to simply contain the appropriate set of instance members. The `implements` clause of a class provides a mechanism to assert and validate that the class contains the appropriate sets of instance members, **but otherwise it has no effect on the class type**.

I added the emphasis above: the `implements` clause does not affect the class type at all; it doesn't add members to it or change the types of members.  All it does is tell the compiler to emit a warning if the class does not conform to the interface.

---

You may be interested in the GitHub issue [microsoft/TypeScript#22815](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22815), which suggests that members of implemented interfaces should be copied down into the implementing classes.  (The title of the issue is about abstract classes, but the ensuing discussion is not limited to that.)  It looks like the sticking point is what to do about optional members (see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22815#issuecomment-410889037) by the TS team lead).  The issue is an older one, but it's still open with a "needs proposal" tag, so if you care a lot about it you might want to go there, give it a , and maybe even give more details on what the behavior should be in edge cases so that it wouldn't be a breaking change.

Inside that issue is a suggested [workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22815#issuecomment-375766197) using [interface merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) to tell the compiler that the class instance interface inherits properties:

```
interface FooModel extends IFoo { } // merge into FooModel
class FooModel {
    constructor({ foo, bar }: IFoo = { foo: 'hello', bar: 1 }) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

This is less redundant but might be more confusing than just redeclaring the properties from the interface.

---

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQDEII4BvAKDmrnRIC44BnGKZAcwG4qaAjTKIyQBXALa803AL4UKyVBhx5iEALIQAJsAA2cUKiQamBFeThS4AektxRadnhgALBEwrZtmJsZXqtuyho4bAgkFihhbBhoAAoyWhIAGjh+KHNGIhI4AF4zOghGAHInHW0IQuTUxgBGcwBKch4g6mdXADp8nISIbmaaVqY21K7U3poZGVBIWDgtLGFteF9NHU4gA)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an interface, you could use an `abstract class`. Same benefits as an interface, but with the possibility of extending it:

```
export abstract class IFoo {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}

export default class FooModel extends IFoo {
  constructor({ foo, bar }: IFoo = { foo: 'hello', bar: 1 }) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the advantages and disadvantages of this? If looks kinda odd to have a class as an interface

Comment: there are no disadvantages, you can use it as an `interface` as well by using `implements`, but then you have to define the fields as you did before. It's just a nice thingy of typescript

Comment: also, when using an abstract class, as long as you don't extend it, it doesn't get included in the emit, so it saves bytes

Comment: This sounds interesting, does this work with type casting too like an interface? Like: `const NewFoo: IFoo = { foo: "hi", bar: 2 };`

Comment: @Nurfey definitely, no issues [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwEYGcZQQY3pgNglFOASQDEII4BvAKDjgDMKB+ALjjSgEsA7AcwDcdOEgRQ2cHgFcAtkmBQhAXxo1MEHmjgA5YAHdyEdmQpwAvNUYV2AIgAWXGwBoRY9gCY4SgUA)

Comment: This is not the right way to go about it. In the playground, you have made the properties optional which may not be desired.

Answer (score 0):

If you define an interface with only properties you basically defined a data structure type that you can then use to type objects.

For example you could now do this:

```
const fooObj: IFoo = { foo: "test", bar: 12 };
```

In other programming languages (eg. Java) it is illegal to define properties on an interface. An interface "normally" defines a way you can interact with an object (meaning methods you can invoke on it). But TypeScript is an exception to this.

Comment: I indeed use it for the data structure and DTO's, which is why I need it, but I think I probably shouldn't be using interfaces for DTO's but it works fine and it makes mapping easy

Comment: @Nurfey I understand. But implementing an interface that has only properties make no sense to me. As an interface is like a "contract" the class has to implement. If there are no methods, there is also no contract.

Comment: Makes sense, is there an alternative for also having type casting with property autocompletion..?

Comment: @Nurfey I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you could update your question with some more information on that? Not only the problem you ran into, but what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I followed your advice, and I indeed did not need an interface since I can just use the model for the type assignment f.e.: `const foo: FooModel = new FooModel();`, I used to do: `const foo: IFoo = new FooModel();`, the new one just makes much more sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Nurfey thanks for reporting back. In this case one usually doesn't include the type, because it disturbs the readability and is not necessary. So `const foo = new FooModel();` would be enough. Just like `const num = 5;` is enough and you don't need to write `const num: number = 5;`